# Typing React functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am writing a React application using functional components and decided on usnig TypeScript. I know how to type parameters and their return values of functions:

`const myFunc: string = (a:number, b:number): string => a + '' + b`

But how can I specify that my React component returns an array of other components?

Given component A in a.tsx:

`export default const A = (props) => <div>Count {props.count}</div>`

and component B in b.tsx:

```
import A from './a';
const B = (list: number[]) => list.map(el => <A count={el}>)
```

I tried 
`const B = (list: number[]): A[] => list.map(el => <A count={el}>)`
but that gives the error that A is used here as a value while a type is expected. Makes sense but then, what is the type of a component?

How can I type a React functional component that outputs a collection of React components?

Comment: Why do you want to define it specifically as returning an array? Normally you just use `React.FC<YourPropsTypeHere>`...

Comment: (Not a dig, a question. :-) Just re-read it and it looked like a dig.)

Comment: ...since I'm returning an array of React components I figure I have to specify that. Analogous to a component returning an array of numbers: const getArray():number[] = {...}. I find very little information on typing a component return value, all is about typing props, e.g https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#function-components

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to say specifically that the component returns an array. Typically you use `React.FC` with a type parameter for what your component takes as props:

```
import A from './a';

const B: React.FC<{list: number[]}> = ({list}) => list.map((el, i) => <A key={i} count={el}/>);
```

or

```
import A from './a';

interface BProps {
    list: number[];
}
const B: React.FC<BProps> = ({list}) => list.map((el, i) => <A key={i} count={el}/>);
```

Three side notes on that:

- `list` is a property of the props object. In your question it was its own formal parameter.
- You need the closing `/` on the `A` component.
- Presumably `B` will be used within another component, so the entries in the array need to have a `key` property. The above uses their position in the list, but I recommend reading [this information](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) about keys and about using indexes as keys. Basically, if the list may be reordered, don't use indexes as keys. :-)

Comment: Ok, great, thanks. I changed my FC call. Thi sis what I have

Comment: Ok, great, thanks. I changed my FC call to:

const makeRows: React.FC<{ board: TCard[]; nrOfColumns: number; onClickCard: Function }> = (
 board,
 nrOfColumns,
 onClickCard
) => {
 const rows = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
  if (i % nrOfColumns === 0) {
   rows.push(<Row cards={board.slice(i, i + nrOfColumns)} onClick={onClickCard} />);
  }
 }
 return rows;
};
I get:
Type '(board: any, nrOfColumns: any, onClickCard: any) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FC<{ board: TCard[]; nrOfColumns: number; onClickCard: Function; }>'.

Seems to ignore the typings?

Comment: ...hmmm comments don't allow for formatting obviously.

Comment: @Marc - That's because you're trying to accept them as discrete parameters. They aren't, they're properties on props (the second bullet point above). You can use destructuring in the parameter list (note the `{}`): `const makeRows: React.FC<{ board: TCard[]; nrOfColumns: number; onClickCard: Function }> = ( { board, nrOfColumns, onClickCard } ) =>`.

Comment: FWIW, if the props are more than just one simple thing, I'd use an interface (second example above), but it's a style call. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments .Not quite sure if my issue is clear - it's related to specifying the return type of a F component, not how to type the props. React.FC<PropTypes> does not relate to the return type...

Comment: @Marc - That's what I address with the first sentence of the answer. There's no need to say specifically you're returning an array.